# Как осуществить вывод результата работы потоков по заданному кванту времени

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Я не могу придумать как сделать синхронизацию логов потоков.
Алгоритм «первый подходящий» (First-Fit) метода FCFS.
Задача: осуществить вывод состояния параллельных потоков каждый заданный квант времени. Потоки -  это студенты, ресурсы - это профессоры, у каждого студента несколько предметов к сдаче и у каждого профессора лимит одновременно возможных студентов на экзамене.
Входные тестовые данные:

- Поток-1 имеет задачи с ресурсами [р1, р2, р3] и burst = 2.
- Поток-2 имеет задачи с ресурсами [р2, р3] и burst = 3.
- Поток-3 имеет задачи с   ресурсами [р2, р3] и burst = 3.
- Ресурсы имеют лимит доступа: р1 = 1, р2 = 1, р3 = 2.

В идеале должна получиться такая картина (И – исполнение потока (сотояние Running), О – состояние потока в ожидании ресурсов (сотояние Waiting), З – поток завершен (сотояние Dead)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так я осуществил работу алгоритма:

```
public class FCFS implements Algoritm {
    private List<Student> studentsList;
    private Student currentStudent;
    private List<Student> finishedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    public static HashMap<String, Professor> professorsMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static ArrayBlockingQueue<Student> threadsQueueFCFS;
    public FCFS(List<Student> studentsList, HashMap<String, Professor> professorsMap) {
        this.studentsList = studentsList;
        this.professorsMap = professorsMap;
    }

    private ArrayBlockingQueue<Student> addArrayBlockingQueueThreads(List<Student> threads) {
        ArrayBlockingQueue<Student> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(threads.size());
        queue.addAll(threads);
        return queue;
    }


    @Override
    public void schedule() throws InterruptedException {
        threadsQueueFCFS = addArrayBlockingQueueThreads(studentsList);//очередь потоков
        String currentTask = null;
        int sizeAllWork = threadsQueueFCFS.size();
        int q = studentsList.size();
        while(finishedTasks.size() < sizeAllWork) {//пока очередь законченных работу потоков меньше плановой
            int counter = 0;//счетчик поиска свободных ресурсов
            currentStudent = threadsQueueFCFS.take();
            if (currentStudent.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                currentStudent.setName(currentStudent.getNameStudent());
                currentStudent.start();
            }
            if (currentStudent.getStatus().equals("ready")) {
                currentTask = currentStudent.getTasks().get(counter);
                while (true) {
                //если семафор Петри свободен, занимает его.
                    if (professorsMap.get(currentTask).getSemaforPetri().close()) {
                        //устанавливаем параметры работы потока (предмет и burst)
                        currentStudent.setWork(counter, currentStudent.getBurst());
                        currentStudent.setStatus("work");
                        threadsQueueFCFS.put(currentStudent);
                        break;
                    } else { //реализация First-Fit - ищем другой свободный ресурс
                        if (counter + 1 <= currentStudent.getTasks().size() - 1) {
                            counter++;
                            currentTask = currentStudent.getTasks().get(counter);
                        } else {//нет ни одного свободного ресурса - переводим в ожидание
                            currentStudent.setStatus("wait");
                            threadsQueueFCFS.put(currentStudent);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentStudent.getStatus().equals("dead")) {
                currentStudent.interrupt();
                finishedTasks.add(currentStudent);
            } else {
                threadsQueueFCFS.put(currentStudent);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printResult() {
        long timeAlgoritm = 0;
        for (Student thread : finishedTasks) {
            if (thread.getWorkTimeThread() > timeAlgoritm) {
                timeAlgoritm = thread.getWorkTimeThread();
            }
            System.out.println(thread.getName() + ": "  + thread.getLogMap().entrySet());
        }
        System.out.println("Статистика профессоров.");
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Professor> entry : professorsMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Профессор по " +
                    entry.getValue().getNameExam() +
                    " принял: "  + entry.getValue().getCounter() +
                    " студента(ов)");
        }
    }
}
```

Так я осуществил работу потока:

```
public class Student extends Thread {
    private ArrayList<String> disciplines;
    private String nameStudent, status;
    private int burst, prioritet, time, taskIndex, workTime, currentBurst;
    private long workTimeThread, startTimeThread;
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> logMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Student(String nameStudent, int prioritet, int burst, ArrayList<String> disciplines) {
        this.nameStudent = nameStudent;
        this.prioritet = prioritet;
        this.burst = burst;
        this.disciplines = disciplines;
        this.time = 0;
        this.startTimeThread = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.workTimeThread = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.status = "ready";
        this.currentBurst = burst;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTasks() {
        return disciplines;
    }

    public String getNameStudent() {
        return nameStudent;
    }

    public int getBurst() {
        return burst;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public int getPrioritet() {
        return prioritet;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public long getWorkTimeThread() {
        return workTimeThread;
    }
    
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> getLogMap() {
        return logMap;
    }

    public void setTasks(ArrayList<String> disciplines) {
        this.disciplines = disciplines;
    }

    public void setNameStudent(String nameStudent) {
        this.nameStudent = nameStudent;
    }

    public void setBurst(int burst) {
        this.burst = burst;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setPrioritet(int prioritet) {
        this.prioritet = prioritet;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setWork(int taskIndex, int workTime) {
        this.taskIndex = taskIndex;
        this.workTime = workTime;
    }

    private void workResorce() throws InterruptedException {
        while (workTime != 0) {
            sleep(quant);
            setTime(time + quant);
            logMap.put(time, status + "(" + disciplines.get(taskIndex) + ")");
            currentBurst = workTime - quant;
            workTime = workTime - quant;
        }
        professorsMap.get(disciplines.get(taskIndex)).getSemaforPetri().open();//это семафор Петри, ограничивает доступ к профессору-ресурсу.
        if (currentBurst <= 0) {
            professorsMap.get(disciplines.get(taskIndex)).setCounterIncrement();
            disciplines.remove(taskIndex);
            currentBurst = burst;
        }
        if (disciplines.isEmpty()) {
            setStatus("dead");
        } else {
            setStatus("ready");
        }
    }

    private void waitResorce() throws InterruptedException {
        setTime(time + quant);
        sleep(quant);
        logMap.put(time, status + "      ");
        setStatus("ready");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "disciplines=" + disciplines +
                ", name='" + getNameStudent() + '\'' +
                ", prioritet=" + prioritet +
                ", burst=" + burst +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                if (status.equals("work")) {
                    workResorce();
                }
                if (status.equals("wait")) waitResorce();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Алгоритм постоянно забирает из очереди потоков threadsQueueFCFS первый, проверяет его статус и в зависимости от этого присваивает ему новый или кладет поток в конец очереди. В случае если свободных ресурсов нет - то переводим поток в ожидание и снова кладем в конец очереди.
Burst имитируется использованием у потока метода sleep(quant). Счетчик количества квантов в классе Student это time.
Алгоритм работает почти правильно, но получается (из-за постоянно разного времени работы потоков до вызова sleep) что в какой то момент в очереди есть поток, который по идее должен проснуться, но не успел, и, алгоритм соответственно отрабатывает но не идеально. Sleep в work и wait не гарантирует мне точного времени равного кванту. Всегда есть еще некоторое время на работу логики.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я прошу подсказать не конкретный код, а дать идею как можно синхронизировать создание логов потоков, чтобы показать работу при некоем идеальном состоянии системы, когда каждый этап work и wait состояния потока был равен заданному кванту времени.